# Ошибка при установке Symfony на сервер | Centos 7

Tags: php, apache, symfony, centos7

Установил и настроил   Apache , php 7.2  на Centos 7 
Теперь пытаюсь установить Symfony

```
composer require symfony/web-server-bundle --dev
```

но получаю такую ошибку

```
[root@81 tracex]# composer require symfony/web-server-bundle --dev
Using version ^4.1 for symfony/web-server-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-bundle ^4.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.0 requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension xml is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for symfony/security-bundle ^4.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/security-bundle v4.1.0 requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension xml is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - symfony/maker-bundle 1.0.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.0.1 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.0.2 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.1.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.1.1 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.2.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.3.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.3.1 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.4.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.4.1 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.4.2 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.4.3 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.4.4 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.5.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.1.0].
    - symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.0 requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension xml is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for symfony/maker-bundle ^1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/maker-bundle[1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.1.0, v1.1.1, v1.2.0, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.4.0, v1.4.1, v1.4.2, v1.4.3, v1.4.4, v1.5.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-bz2.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам же ясно дали понять что не так:

> requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension xml is missing from
>   your system.

Нужно установить `php-xml`, если не ошибаюсь в centos это делается так:

```
yum remi install php-xml
```